# Starting explorer.exe isn't working properly in C#

Tags: c#, process.start

I'm trying to make a simple application in C# that allows me to kill and enable explorer.exe. I need such program so that I can play Age of Empires 2 properly, because it does not like explorer.exe for some reason (I believe it has to do with Aero). So I made two buttons, one that enables explorer.exe and the other one disables it. Killing explorer.exe went ok, but enabling didn't.

I read on a few sites that you have to use the `Process.Start();` to start a process. So I made `Process.Start("explorer.exe");`. After killing explorer.exe, it executed the previous line but instead of having my taskbar back, it opened 'Libraries' only without giving my taskbar back. I also tried `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "-p");` (I saw it somewhere), but that opened 'My Documents'.

What can I do so it starts the process explorer.exe so that I have the things like the taskbar back? I can still launch it properly with Command Prompt/Task Manager/Run.

Comment: Also, this question is fairly similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118017/how-do-i-start-explorer-using-process-class-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in [that](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/687449-how-restart-windows-explorer-using-programme) topic:

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    try
    {
        // Compare it with "explorer".
        if(p.MainModule.ModuleName.Contains("explorer") == true)
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Do some exception handling here.
    }

    // Restart explorer.
    Process.Start("explorer.exe");
}
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: Well, actually the link you gave previously (the one you said was similar to my question) did the trick. I did 
Process.Start(@"c:\\windows\\explorer.exe");
which worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Do not hardcode the path to explorer. Call Envoromment.WindowsDirectory.

Comment: It doesn't really matter though, it's just for my self. Though I'm very new to c#, how would the exact code look like if I do it with Environment.WindowsDirectory? Also visual c# doesn't recognize the 'WindowsDirectory' part.

Comment: @Burak: `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.SystemRoot), "explorer.exe")`

Comment: Good to hear and glad I could help out,